# Have you seen my Harmonica?

Tags: riddle, music

> A limbless veteran seeks euthanasia
>   A sad and lonely person is where two edges meet all the time, though I'm not sure why
>   An ensemble of the musically inclined escaping towards freedom

What phrase/idiom does this represent?

Comment: bob dylan sucks?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry can't say I have heard that Idiom before

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> One Man Band
>  I have a Harmonica you can borrow.

The three lines correspond to three songs.

Song #1

> One - Metallica
>  The clue refers to the book "Johnny Got His Gun" and this song is about it.  The music video includes footage from the movie.

Song #2

> Question asker's intended answer:
>  Man on the Corner by Phil Collins
>  This is about a man on the corner who is there everyday but the singer isn't sure why
>
>  Original Answerer's answer (before edit to remove ambiguity)
>  Man Who Can't Be Moved - The Script
>  This song is about a man who's girlfriend left him so he's camped on a corner and telling people to tell her where to find him.

Song #3

> Band on the Run - Paul McCartney and Wings
>   This one was pretty literal

Final Step

> Take the first words of the song titles and you have your answer.

PS: Bob Dylan is great.